# FizzBuzz game- how to create a comma-separated string

Tags: javascript, function

I should create a function called 'fizzBuzz()' that takes two arguments 'start' and 'stop' and returns a comma-separated string. The arguments represents the starting point and stop point of the game 'Fizz Buzz'. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz). Shortly it means, in a range of numbers I should print all numbers that are divisible by three as Fizz and the numbers divisible by 5 as Buzz, the rest as is. The function should run from start to stop and add 'Fizz', 'Buzz' or both to the 'result'-variable at the appropriate numbers. 
If 'stop' is equal or lower than 'start', the function should return an error message.

```
function fizzBuzz(start, stop) {
 for(var i= start; i <= stop; i++) {{
    if (i % 5 == 0)
        print "Buzz";
    else if (i % 3 == 0)
        print "Fizz";
    else
        print i;
}
 console.log(",")
}
```

My problem is that I don´t know how to make the loop work. Right now when I try to print fizzBuzz(2,24) Nothing comes out. The console tells me that there is semi colon missing at row 4 (same line as "Buzz".

Also, I wonder if this will work with an if/else statement since there are some numbers that are both divisible by 3 and 5. Would it be more clever to use a switch?

Lastly, I want to add an if-statement like the following somewhere. 
if(start == stop || start> stop)
alarm("choose different numbers");

Should it be inside the function? || means "or", is that correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to tag the question with the used programming language (javascript?), and perhaps remove `function`; the latter tag is very generic, and this question isn't specifically about functions.

Comment: If it should *print* the numbers, just replace your `return` statements with `print` functions. With the current `return` statements, you're exiting the function early, and thereby also the `for`-loop.

Comment: Job interview tomorrow? ;)

Comment: Sorry! I am new at this- both on Stack overflow and in the coding world. I am trying my best!

Comment: Thanks Evert, I will try that. And NO, no job interview tomorrow haha :)

Comment: If you `return` in a function, you exit it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code (apart from the extra `{`) is that you are calling `return` in your `for` loop. This causes the function to stop and return only 2.

What you want to do is make a string variable where you add the numbers and then return that. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
function fizzBuzz(start, stop) {
    var returnString = "";
    for (var i= start; i <= stop; i++) {
        if (i % 5 == 0)
            returnString += "Buzz";
        else if (i % 3 == 0)
            returnString += "Fizz";
        else
            returnString += i;
        returnString += ",";
    }
    return returnString;
}
```

**Edit:** Sorry, I didn't see your second question! Yes, you should put the if statement for `if(start == stop || start> stop) alarm("choose different numbers");` at the beginning of the function, before any other code is run (in my example, before `var returnString = "";` but after the `{`). However, there are two things that you should note. First, the function to show a message in JavaScript is `alert`, not `alarm`. Second, you should include a `return;` statement in the `if` after your `alert` so that your function doesn't continue after alerting the user to pick different numbers.

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot. I modified the loop a little bit so that on 15 it would print "FizzBuzz".

Comment: Great! If my answer helped you, could you please mark it as the accepted answer? Click the checkbox on the left (underneath the downvote button).

Comment: Also, about you question for using a switch: a switch statement would not work here because a switch only checks if the number is equal to something else. You cannot put a statement like `i % 5 == 0` into a switch, it won't work. The way you have it here (with `else if`) should be fine.

Comment: Wow, you are great at helping, really. You write it so clear and understandable. I will definitely mark it as an accepted answer!